# MSSQL 2014 "The provided statistics stream is corrupt" Error 9105

Tags: sql-server, statistics

I have a database that prevent to see user properties due to this error.
I've begin investigating and the problem comes from sys.asymmetric_keys and sys.symmetric_keys system views inside the database. 
Both views uses the sys.sysobjvalues table that contains the following statistics:

Stats Name | Column Name
_WA_Sys_00000002_0000003C   objid
_WA_Sys_00000003_0000003C   subobjid
_WA_Sys_00000004_0000003C   valnum
_WA_Sys_00000005_0000003C   value
clst    valclass, objid, subobjid, valnum

The failure appears on the column "value"
DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS ("sys.sysobjvalues",_WA_Sys_00000005_0000003C) that returns:

**Name**
_WA_Sys_00000005_0000003C
*(1 row(s) affected)*

**All density | Avg.Length | Columns**

0,004830 8 |    7,204199      |      value
*(1 row(s) affected)*

**Range_Hi_KEY**
*Msg 9105, Level 16, State 25, Line 43
The provided statistics stream is corrupt.*

Connected using a DAC connection I've tried to delete it (permissions error) and update it without success. The [UPDATE STATISTICS sys.sysobjvalues WITH fullscan, columns] command fails with the "The provided statistics stream is corrupt " error but  [UPDATE STAT.. WITH fullscan, index] works but the error continues.

DBCC CheckDB returns no errors for this table (sys.sysobjvalues).

The server version is: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-CU1) (KB3178925)(Hypervisor)

Any idea on how could I repair this DB without a Restore (All my available restores have the error on it)

Many Thanks

Comment: @hot2use - the OP is on SQL Server 2014. Those fixes are 2008 and 2012

Comment: Deleted previous comment. Could it be a similar bug then? [FIX: "The provided statistics stream is corrupt" when you run the "UPDATE STATISTICS" statement against a table in SQL Server 2008 R2 or SQL Server 2012](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2829845) Might have to call Microsoft. If the sum of all columns is near 8000 then it could be the same issue.

Comment: You could maybe try (on a restored backup somewhere in case it makes things worse) extracting the STATS_STREAM from `sysobjvalues` in a completely different database and reapplying that non corrupted one to this database with `UPDATE STATISTICS ... WITH  STATS_STREAM `

Answer (score 2):

The problem may be in the damaged statistics, and probably in the one that was created automatically

To search for problem statistics you can use:

```
EXEC sp_updatestats
```

exec will iterate over all the tables and statistics, and if there are problems, it will show which statistics, more precisely the table, is the problem.

To remove auto_created statistics, you can use the following script:

```
select 'drop statistics [' + OBJECT_NAME (OBJECT_ID) + '].[' + Name + ']' 
 from sys.stats 
where auto_created = 1 
  and OBJECT_NAME (OBJECT_ID) = 'DB PROBLEM TABLE NAME'
```

The script will generate rows for deleting auto_created statistics for the table "DB PROBLEM TABLE NAME" table

After running the generated lines, rerun

```
EXEC sp_updatestats
```

to check for errors.

Not superfluous would be

```
exec sp_msforeachtable N'UPDATE STATISTICS? WITH FULLSCAN'
```